# Windows 7 doesn't install USB Devices

Tags: windows, drivers

Windows has stopped installing USB devices for me. I tried installing on my dad's windows 7 everything worked fine but it doesn't install for my laptop. Several devices I've tried with have failed whereas they work for other PC's. Windows 7 64 bit. I usually touch a lot of stuff in control panel, msconfig. . e.t.c

Are there any updates of drivers that I need?

If I use VMWare it works properly here's what it showed in VMWare.

[image]

**But here's what happens in device manager on my windows 7 on the same computer**

[image]

Help.

Comment: If you look in device manager, are there any problem devices listed?

Comment: Listing the devices you've tried and the laptop make and model would help. Since this is an uncommon problem, more information is always helpful.

Comment: I  use a HP Pavilion 3030se. The devices install even in my VMWare. I have tried with normal plug and play devices and they don't work. I just tried with my new Android phone and it can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a backup of my documents, factory-reset my OS, and then restored the backup. I honestly do not know where this problem came from.

Answer (score 0):

> I usually touch a lot of stuff in control panel, msconfig. . e.t.c

Something you've 'touched' has disabled Windows' ability to find/search for drivers online.

Might also be worth looking for updated chipset drivers for your laptop, a look on the [HP Website](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/noPfinderResults?query=Pavilion+3030+se&cc=uk&dlc=en&lc=en&tool=) does not display anything for a 'Pavilion 3030se'.