# Where can I get all the default and original drivers for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Where can I get all the default and original drivers Windows 7 came with?

Something like a self extracting archive. My laptop doesn't read new USB devices anymore.

Comment: What laptop is it ? what make and model ? most manufacturer sites have some kind of driver pack you can use ....

Comment: Have you tried using the rollback feature in device manager to return your USB controllers/hubs to the previous working driver?

Comment: Manseuk its a HP Pavilion 3030. Please see http://superuser.com/questions/362688/windows-7-doesnt-install-usb-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a DVD(or a virtual image of it) of Windows 7. All the driver included on the original disc are the default drivers. Try to go to your device manager, right click on the unreconized device, click on update driver and let the device manager find for a driver inside the Windows Seven DVD.

Comment: Didn't work. I just tried it now. Could not find drivers for your hardware. http://superuser.com/questions/362688/windows-7-doesnt-install-usb-devices

Comment: You could also try Windows update to do this.

Comment: @Diogo: The Windows 7 installation DVD contains all files in a single image file. AFAIR 7Zip can read that file. Alternatively you can mount the image using imagex.exe commmand-line tool from "WAIK".